# Alert confirmation box on submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, form-submit

I have a form which submits a value. When the user tries to submit the form I want to display an alert conformation box. Upon clicking `OK`, the value should be saved but if `Cancel` is clicked instead the form should display but not save the data.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo)
<input type="submit" name="name" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: For that you need to have a look at `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: Any possible to using javascript

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo)
<input type="submit" name="name" value="Save" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
}
```

You can use confirm() of javascript in onclick of the button with return.

Comment: where is the condition if ok is pressed or cancel is pressed

Comment: no need for condition. if user press ok it returns true then click perform or user click cancel retrun false and no click perform.
"return confirm('Are you sure?')"  is working as condition check

Comment: when using with `<button form="myform">` it doesn't submit on OK

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo)
<input type="submit" name="name" value="Save" onclick="javascript: return SubmitForm();" />
}
```

javascript

```
function SubmitForm() {

var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?");
  if (r == false) {
    return false;
  }       
}
```